# Why does TLS use two separate sequence numbers?

Tags: tls, hmac

In TLS separate implicit sequence numbers for sent and received packets are used to calculate the HMAC in the record layer. The RFC 5246 says:

> Each connection state contains a sequence number, which is maintained
> separately for read and write states.

Why do I need separate sequence numbers? Why can't two parties share the same one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS is for bidirectional traffic, i.e. there are separate data streams for each direction which can have a different position in the data stream. That's why one also needs two sequence numbers to describe these positions. Same as with TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Because the two sides don't take turns transmitting. Both sides transmit at the same time.